# Find most common word in a list of sets

Tags: python

I'm currently working in my university projects in NLP. I'd like to display the most common words contained in this list of sets:

`[{'allow', 'feel', 'fear', 'situat', 'properti', 'despit', 'face', 'ani'}, {'unpleas', 'someth', 'fear', 'make', 'abil', 'face', 'scar', 'us', 'feel'}]`

This is what I've accomplished until now:

```
def word_list(sent):
   if isinstance(sent, str):
       tokens = set(word_tokenize(sent.lower()))
   else:
       tokens = set([t for s in sent for t in word_tokenize(s.lower())])
   tokens = set([stemmer.stem(t) for t in tokens])

   for w in stopword_final:
       tokens.discard(w)
   return tokens
   
def get_most_relevant_words(definitions):
   list_of_words = list()
   most_common_word_dict = dict()
   for d1 in definitions:
       list_of_words.append(word_list(d1))

   for elem in list_of_words:
    for word in elem:
        print(word)
        word_counter = Counter(word)
        most_occurrences = word_counter.most_common(3)
        most_common_word_dict.update({word: most_occurrences})
        return most_common_word_dict
```

The desired output should be: `{fear: 2, feel: 2}`

The output that it prints is: `{'feel': [('e', 2), ('f', 1), ('l', 1)]}`

Comment: When I run this code, it doesn't print anything.

Comment: And if I try to pass the list of sets to any of the two functions you have defined I get an error `name 'word_tokenize' is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

list_of_sets = [{'allow', 'feel', 'fear', 'situat', 'properti', 'despit', 'face', 'ani'}, {'unpleas', 'someth', 'fear', 'make', 'abil', 'face', 'scar', 'us', 'feel'}]
words = [word for my_set in list_of_sets for word in my_set]
c = Counter(words)
print(c)
```

output:

```
Counter({
    'fear': 2, 
    'face': 2, 
    'feel': 2, 
    'properti': 1, 
    'despit': 1, 
    'allow': 1, 
    'situat': 1, 
    'ani': 1, 
    'someth': 1, 
    'unpleas': 1, 
    'make': 1, 
    'abil': 1, 
    'us': 1, 
    'scar': 1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate through the 2 sets, find common terms, and update the count in a dictionary.  By the way, 'face' should also be included in your result.

```
lst = [{'allow', 'feel', 'fear', 'situat', 'properti', 'despit', 'face', 'ani'}, {'unpleas', 'someth', 'fear', 'make', 'abil', 'face', 'scar', 'us', 'feel'}]
dic = {}
for word1 in lst[0]:
    for word2 in lst[1]:
        if word1 == word2:
            dic[word1] = dic.get(word1, 0) + 2

print(dic)
#{'fear': 2, 'feel': 2, 'face': 2}
```